# In express can I have a a sub route if theres already a param on that route

Tags: node.js, express, routes, routeparams

If I have route `/auth/token/:token` where `:token` is my param, would it still be possible to have route `/auth/token/exchange/:code`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is Possible to have both the routes

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get("/auth/token/exchange/:token", function(req, res) {
    res.send(req.params)
})
app.get("/auth/token/:token", function(req, res) {
    res.send(req.params)
})


app.listen(4000, function() {
    console.log("Express server listening on port 4000");
});
```